# (Brand new to coding) Can someone tell me what the invalid syntax is here?

Tags: python

#This is code to add a counter so someone can only try 3 times at a game.

```
login == false
    counter = 0
    while counter < 3: and login == false
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Have you tried `while counter < 3 and login == false:` ?

Comment: I have and it sadly didnt work the error message is SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: No "at line ..." ?

Comment: Oh the first line .. is that supposed to be `login = false` ?

Comment: I changes that earlier but it didn't work do you know a better way of doing this counter ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this?

```
login = False
counter = 0
while counter < 3 and login == False:
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

So Change false to False (capital F) and fixed the indents and removed one = sign in the beginning

Comment: Thank you that was very usefull

Comment: @DhanishMahmood if it was the solution please mark it as solved so your question will be marked as solved